# Can I use the combination "multi-adjective+noun"?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, hyphens, noun-phrases, prefixes

I'd like to learn if I can use the combination "multi-adjective+noun" to form an adjective.
Examples;

> This is a multi-rigid-body analysis.

(I mean that *this analysis has more than one rigid body*. I know "*This is a multi-body analysis*" is correct but it is not exactly what I'd like to say)

> It is a multi-powerful-core processor.

(I mean that *this processor has more than one powerful core*. I know "*It is a multi-core processor*" is correct but it is again not exactly what I'd like to say.)
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that; for example,

> [Commercially available Blackhat SEO enabled **multi-third-party** product licenses empowered VPSs spotted in the wild](https://www.webroot.com/blog/2013/10/04/commercially-available-blackhat-seo-enabled-multi-third-party-bhseo-product-licenses-empowered-vps-servers-spotted-wild/)

or

> [On multi-rigid-body system dynamics](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0045794979900191)

But your example of *It is a multi-powerful-core processor* is awkward and non-fluent.  "Multi-rigid-body analysis" looks OK because we would write "rigid-body analysis"; *rigid body* is a fixed phrase with a specific meaning, which we consider as a single element.  But we probably wouldn't write "it is a powerful-core processor" because it's not very clear what it is trying to say; *powerful core* is not a fixed phrase like *rigid body* is.  It would sound more fluent to write **it is a powerful multi-core processor** if that is acceptably close to what you want to say, or otherwise **it is a processor with multiple powerful cores**.